# How to infer value type iusing using "dotted path" inside interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create generic interface for table column

And I want typescript infer type of 'value' inside 'render' by using 'field' (that uses "dotted path")

But it inferred that 'value' has type of all values of RowData
What I do wrong ?

```
type Paths<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = K extends string
    ? T[K] extends Record<string, any>
        ? T[K] extends ArrayLike<any>
            ? `${K}.${Paths<T[K], Exclude<keyof T[K], keyof any[]>>}`
            : `${K}.${Paths<T[K], keyof T[K]>}`
        : K
    : never;

type FieldValue<T, Path extends string> = string extends Path
    ? unknown
    : Path extends keyof T
    ? T[Path]
    : Path extends `${infer K}.${infer R}`
    ? K extends keyof T
        ? FieldValue<T[K], R>
        : unknown
    : unknown;

type Flat<T> = { [k in Paths<T>]: FieldValue<T, k> };

export interface TableColumn<D, K extends keyof Flat<D> = keyof Flat<D>> {
    title: string;
    readonly field?: K;
    render?: (options: { row: D; value: Flat<D>[K] }) => string;
}

interface RowData {
  a: number;
  b: {
    c: string
  }
}

const d: TableColumn<RowData> = {
    title: 'Title',
    field: 'b.c',
    render: ({ value }) => value // value type is string | number but expected string because  RowData['b.c'] is string
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgQxACwM4B4AqAaGBpGKADxCgDsATVGAayjAHsAzGTGAXlvudYD4P8hEuSoxUIAE4BLMgHNgASAD8rANp4AukNKVqAJSgBjBhIrpx0ubgRkwvRcrWbtI6gEEJEhGAAyUuug2dg6OAAYAJADeeAC%20AHRRiCgYmOoauACiRIYANgCuFFDodIwsqZq4JTxBqhq8vDGhIQBcMBHR8YlIaFhpldxlaQ1NCgqteIqtZFAAblASANzAoJCwAGJSUDkUAGoI%20UU48N0uumKSMrL8nBaXp6JJyIoqeWQ0ZAwA7mSTxyj31CqZWeakeGl%20jwBbSiMiY83wnUisPhekaIIIxB0oiBrAcKg2W12%20zyhz6MD09lGrVe7y%20PzGMBpH2%20SxW0BgaxySCw1xgkRgqhoMBkfx6mF4GlaBO2ewOWEq-BirOIEBMIGFZFIEiYCEMsEwCAARjkoABhBj5AC2ZHQABFcBjhGccZzubbeS6uSA7fU%20YoJFAEBQGGQcmAYExNtslOMlgoA5R5jGYAAKBgQEBSEOoVr8iRfVq2hYwGbEqBSr0%20tIwGIASg4-FuciWMWWMi1Or15K%20tqQCD9MBgCCmeUthvmS0HhtzwEHg8MrSb8kHrdbwGMZHEMAorQNxrNFtHNr0Pb7vMiikzIBNrQA5JgpNeoLfsIpI4S74a4oYX-6RPNWhTflSwOGt63YfgQJJGAAHoYJLMsYHAdkpGoJcYAAHxgMhR3HCQYENPJ1RVIxSAoc5LFkAijAQPJUFgbtPl7EAEFUW8vx-LRUIoy5gCVIA)

Comment: You wrote `TableColumn<RowData>` which is the same as `TableColumn<RowData, "a" | "b.c">`. Thus both `field` and `render` could correspond to either `"a"` or `"b.c"` or the union of them. If you want something else, either you need to write `TableColumn<RowData, "b.c">`, or you need to write a generic helper function to infer `K` from the object literal, or you need to rewrite `TableColumn` as a union type itself and then can't be an interface. Which way would you like to proceed?  Or are you just asking what you're doing wrong, in which case I can write up the above explanation as an answer?

Comment: And `title` seems to be an excess property, so what's going on there?  An object literal will complain about excess properties; could you remove `title` or add it to `TableColumn`'s definition?

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mAydZm) is one way you could solve it if you allow a union type for `TableColumn`.

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of

```
interface TableColumn<D, K extends keyof Flat<D> = keyof Flat<D>>
```

gives the `K` type parameter a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `keyof Flat<D>`.  If you write `TableColumn<RowData>`, it means `TableColumn<RowData, keyof Flat<D>>`.  It does *not* mean "please infer the best `K` for me"; TypeScript doesn't have type parameter inference for generic types.  And `TableColumn<RowData, keyof Flat<D>>` means something like

```
{
   field: "a" | "b.c",
   render?: (options: { row: RowData; value: string | number }) => string;
}
```

Oops.

---

So either you need to write `TableColumn<RowData, "b.c">` explicitly, or you need to write a generic helper function to have `K` inferred for you, or you need to rewrite `TableColumn<D>` to be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where each member of the union corresponds to a particular choice of `K`.

This last one is often what people want, although you can't make it an `interface`.  Let's see it:

```
type TableColumn<D> = { [K in keyof Flat<D>]: {
    title: string;
    readonly field?: K;
    render?: (options: { row: D; value: Flat<D>[K] }) => string;
} }[keyof Flat<D>]
```

Here I've made `TableColumn<D>` a *distributive object type* as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  A type of the form `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]` *distributes* the `F<P>` operation over all the keys in `K`.  And we want to distribute your original `TableColumn<D, K>` over all the keys in `keyof Flat<D>`.  Here's what comes out for `TableColumn<RowData>`:

```
type RowDataTableColumn = TableColumn<RowData>;
/* type RowDataTableColumn = {
    title: string;
    readonly field?: "a" | undefined;
    render?: ((options: {
        row: RowData;
        value: number;
    }) => string) | undefined;
} | {
    title: string;
    readonly field?: "b.c" | undefined;
    render?: ((options: {
        row: RowData;
        value: string;
    }) => string) | undefined;
} */
```

And then things work how you want:

```
const d: TableColumn<RowData> = {
    title: 'Title',
    field: 'b.c',
    render: ({ value }) => value // okay
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-VWt1+t7H37IAQvEWAHoAFQwRWby-b1Un-d6gRRe2O51iEucjhl6Pp+gGQb4tGABECDQTAAA+lKRkGUwUCBkYSNGMZxgmUhJrOCgeumpJbte7oKDm+yjuOk4LCuFbsFWQGyBWSEvIUqFQOha6IUODpOnmgGWG6iiet6vr+oGwYUDBKrxIY8HsShMjcRhhRYa0OHxomZDJkOxEfK0F5XggFFUUSi4ie65aVsJlxschnGqTxtYPneSzGHpIAwBQrTHnuZ7oCZA7Gn+gmtAA5Jg-5QJF2CKJBWxRfJhjxWJIhzFpPIWbAtlMdmuYwHed4wAwNA+Gu8xAA)